Why do I get different results when I use either values or variables when coding an exponentiation?
The following code gives different output and I can't tell why. I have basic programming knowledge so forgive me if its obvious.
Num = -0.8

Print(-0.8**-0.8)

Print(Num**Num) 

Output:
-1.1954406247375462

(-0.967131781178879-0.7026623692120304j)

Why does the second output give an imaginary number as the output? I basically want the first output but using variables instead of the actual number.
I tried print(-(Num)**Num)) because I thought it was an operator precedence issue but it was still the same result. The difference in output is only apparent with negative floats by the way.

The first output is not what you get from raising -0.8 to the power of -0.8. If that's what you want Num**Num to produce, you need to fix your expectations.

** has higher precedence than unary -. So -0.8**-0.8 is - (0.8**-0.8), which represents −(0.8−0.8), about −1.1954406247375462.
(-0.8)**-0.8 gives the same result as the Num**Num expression, (-0.967131781178879-0.7026623692120304j).

I basically want the first output but using variables instead of the actual number.

That is not going to work with Num**Num given your assignment of −0.8 to Num. −1.1954406247375462 is not a correct result for that exponentiation. If instead you assign 0.8 to Num, you could use - Num**-Num.

Totally understand now. tripped me up a bit but makes sense now

With parentheses it works better:
Num = -0.8

print((-0.8)**(-0.8))

print(Num**Num) 

result:
(-0.967131781178879-0.7026623692120304j)
(-0.967131781178879-0.7026623692120304j)

